# XSLT match with different conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to output different nodes based on the content tags of my input xml.

As you will see in my transformation, i want to recognize, if a shut has SHU_CODE=10, 6, 7, 8, 9, it should go into a NODE node, but if its SHU_CODE=4, it should go into a separate NODE.

Then within each node i apply the transformation to each specific shut.

The problem i am having is that i cannot manage to have separate the nodes, all goes to de same NODE.

This is the input xml:

```
  <Inserts>
    <Shuts>
      <Shut>
        <SHU_CODE>10</SHU_CODE>
      </Shut>
      <Shut>
        <SHU_CODE>4</SHU_CODE>
      </Shut>
    </Shuts>
  </Inserts>
```

And this is my expected output:

```
<NODE>
    <SHUT workcenter='10'/>
</NODE>
<NODE>
    <SHUT workcenter='4'/>
</NODE>
```

This is part of my xsl transformation:

```
<xsl:template match="Inserts/Shuts[Shut/SHU_CODE='10'] 
    | Inserts/Shuts[Shut/SHU_CODE='6'] 
    | Inserts/Shuts[Shut/SHU_CODE='7']
    | Inserts/Shuts[Shut/SHU_CODE='8']
    | Inserts/Shuts[Shut/SHU_CODE='9']">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>NODE<xsl:text 

disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Shut[SHU_CODE='10'] 
| Shut[SHU_CODE='6'] 
| Shut[SHU_CODE='7'] 
| Shut[SHU_CODE='8'] 
| Shut[SHU_CODE='9']"/>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/</xsl:text>NODE<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Inserts/Shuts[Shut/SHU_CODE='4']">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>NODE<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Shut[SHU_CODE='4']"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/</xsl:text>NODE<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What would the output look like if you had both a `<SHU_CODE>10</SHU_CODE>` and a `<SHU_CODE>9</SHU_CODE>` in your input XML? Do you want just one `NODE` output in this case?

Comment: If you want to create a `NODE` result element you can and should simply use  a literal result element e.g. `<NODE>...</NODE>` in XSLT. As for the problem, it is not clear to me whether you want to group certain elements together. Currently I think you have templates matching on `Shuts` with the same priority and when both templates match you either get an error or the last matching template is used.

Comment: @TimC, indeed, if SHU_CODE is 9 or 10, i want them in the same node.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, later in the XSLT i have a matching tempalte for shut, which transforms any shut element with the format i want. <xsl:template match="Shut">... Thanks

Comment: So which version of XSLT do you use or can you use? It sounds as if you want to group/wrap elements with certain values together.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am using version 1, don´t know if i could use any other version but i could try. As you describe, i want to group/wrap elements with common values together.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can move to XSLT 2 or 3 you can do it easily with `xsl:for-each-group`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="Shuts">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Shut" group-by="SHU_CODE = 4">
          <NODE>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </NODE>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Shut">
      <SHUT workcenter="{SHU_CODE}"/>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFB has an online sample. In XSLT 1 grouping is usually done with Muenchian grouping and a key.

If you want to form different groups based on different values you need some way to define those groups, assuming XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 one could use a sequence of array and then check the index inside e.g. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFB/1 which does

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs array mf"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="group-keys" as="array(xs:integer)*" select="[4], [11], array{6 to 10}"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:group-index" as="xs:integer">
      <xsl:param name="seq-of-arrays" as="array(xs:integer)*"/>
      <xsl:param name="code" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="for $pos in 1 to count($seq-of-arrays)
                            return $pos[array:flatten($seq-of-arrays[$pos]) = $code]"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="Shuts">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Shut" group-by="mf:group-index($group-keys, SHU_CODE)">
          <NODE>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </NODE>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Shut">
      <SHUT workcenter="{SHU_CODE}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are `SHU_CODE=4, SHU_CODE=11` forming one group? Then you only need to change the `group-by` to `group-by="SHU_CODE=4 or SHU_CODE=11"` or more compact `group-by="SHU_CODE = (4, 11)"`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually 4 and 11 should be in separate groups. (4), (11), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10). I managed to make it work by adding several templates, each with a different for-each-group... puting the for-each-group in the same template, duplicates the output. If there is a shorter way to achieve this, appriciated.

Comment: See the edit or for XSLT 2, although this constructs a complex `group-by` expression, you can use `group-by="if (SHU_CODE = 4) then 1 else if (SHU_CODE = 11) then 2 else 3"`.